# Pycharm file changes propagate to multiple environments

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

When using PyCharm, I have noticed that if I change a file in one conda environment's path, sometimes those changes propagate into other environments. What is causing this and is there a way to make it stop? For a little background, the code editor is pinned to a specific environment, and then I have multiple terminal tabs also open in pycharm. If I edit a file in either the pycharm terminal using vim or the pycharm editor, the changes propagate to the corresponding file in other environments. In my various open terminal tabs, I have different environments activated, not necessarily the one that my code editor is pinned to. Am I misusing PyCharm in a way that is causing this strange behavior?

Thanks and best regards,

-PolyyloP

Comment: `a file` in this context is some script or similar that you have written yourself?

Comment: `A file` is some python file that is part of a package that was conda installed into my environment and lives in `/path_to_conda/envs/env_name/lib/python*/site-packages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda install` performs soft or hard linking instead of actually copying a package's content in every env.

You should see a different behavior if you use `conda install --copy` to install the package.